# Keep keys in synchronisation between Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with a "master" sheet that has a list of rows (first column is a key and in the other are some data). I want to be able to have more sheets in the document that would have the same list of keys but just different kind of data associated with each key.

I tried `importrange` and it does almost what I want except if I add a new key in the middle of the list in the master spreadsheet, the data on the other spreadsheets doesn't move down with their corresponding keys (only the list of keys shifts down).

How can I tie the data to the keys in the other spreadsheet?

Comment: `importrange` is meant for importing data from another spreadsheet. If you are referring to another sheet in the same spreadsheet, it's easier to use `=arrayformula(master!A:A)`. This does not solve the problem, though. The options I see are (1) develop a pretty complex script that will hopefully keep the data in sync; (2) always add new keys at the end of key list; (3) rethink the data organization (if you want rows to sync between different sheets, maybe the data should really be within the same sheet?).

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92966/sync-multiple-cells-so-that-if-any-one-of-them-is-changed-the-others-change-as/92977