# Sync multiple cells so that if any one of them is changed, the others change as well

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have 4 hard coded cells on 4 different sheets (within a google sheet file) that I'd like to keep synced. If any of those four cells have been changed, I'd like the other three cells to be updated to that changed value. The trick is that all four can be changed manually. Is there an app script that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this can be done. The function `sync` should be set to trigger on edit (via Resources > Current project's triggers). The arrays in the first two lines should be filled with sheet names and cell names that you want to sync.

If the edited cell matches one of those, then the rest will be updated to have the same value.

```
function sync(e) {
  var sheetName = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];  // name of sheets
  var cell = ['A1', 'B2', 'B1', 'A1'];    // corresponding cells to sync
  var r = e.range;
  var ss = e.source;
  var value = (e.value === undefined ? '' : e.value);
  var i = sheetName.indexOf(r.getSheet().getSheetName()); 
  if (i > -1 && r.getA1Notation() == cell[i]) {
    for (var k = 0; k < sheetName.length; k++) {
      if (k != i) {
        ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[k]).getRange(cell[k]).setValue(value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want! Thank you so much!